# How do I change element value based on the data attribute?

Tags: javascript

I've tried using textContent and innerHTML, but haven't been able to change hello world to goodbye.

```
<div data-test='hello'>
hello world
</div>

var test = document.querySelectorAll("[data-test='hello']");
//test.textContent = "goodbye";
test.innerHTML = "goodbye";
```

Comment: Look at what [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns versus what [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns

Comment: as @PatrickEvans suggested; you are returning an array instead of returning a single element. See documentation for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Definition by documentation*: The querySelectorAll() method returns all elements in the document that matches a specified CSS selector(s), as a static NodeList object.

The [`querySelectorAll`](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) method return an `array`, then you can change the first element as follow:

```js
var test = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test="hello"]');
test[0].innerHTML = "goodbye";
```

```html
<div data-test='hello'>
  hello world
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change querySelectorAll to querySelector

```
<div data-test='hello'>
    hello world
</div>
<script>
    var test = document.querySelector("[data-test='hello']");
    //test.textContent = "goodbye";
    test.innerHTML = "goodbye";
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9evue27z/

Answer (score 1):

If there is a possibility of having more than one element with `data-test`, you can still use `document.querySelectorAll`.

```
var test = document.querySelectorAll("[data-test='hello']");
for (var i = 0; i <= test.length; i++) {
    test[i].innerHTML = "goodbye";
}

// or using newer syntax
test.forEach(x => x.innerHTML = "goodbye");
```